# Do anybody know how jQuery Flot "mode: time" works?

Tags: jquery, flot

Do somebody know how the jQuery Flot mode: time works?

```
yaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%H:%M"

},
```

The jQuery Api ship it easy in the docs:
http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

How should you give the data to the graph? In seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the API it states:

> The time series support in Flot is based on Javascript timestamps,
>   i.e. everywhere a time value is expected or handed over, a Javascript
>   timestamp number is used. This is a number, not a Date object. A
>   Javascript timestamp is **the number of milliseconds since January 1,
>   1970 00:00:00 UTC.** This is almost the same as Unix timestamps, except
>   it's in milliseconds, so remember to multiply by 1000!

Here is a pretty good [example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html).

Comment: I think that reflects to the x axis and i have got and other answer that i have to use tickFormatter :)

Comment: I believe it works on either axis.  In the options you specify:  { xaxis: { mode: "time" }, yaxis: { mode: "time" } }

Comment: Can we make it use timestamp in seconds instead of milliseconds by default??